# Ecobee3 lite no output for the O/B pin

Tags: hvac

The compressor runs but no cooling (Goodman reverse cycle) The old thermostat worked so I am sure the O/B lead is good. Any way to determine if the Ecobee is at fault or unthinkable operator error! Thanks

Comment: Is the heat pump able to heat the building with the Ecobee connected, but not cool it? Have you checked the settings to ensure your Ecobee is configured for a heat pump system?

Comment: It does heat. There is a pin on the Ecobee for the reversing valve. When in the cooling mode I don't believe the valve is energized via the O/B lead. When in the heating mode, the valve is not energized. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Setup has an option for energizing reversing valve when cooling. Works fine now

Answer (score 1):

### Check your equipment configuration

You need to go into your Ecobee's configuration menus and make sure that your equipment type is set to a heat pump, not a conventional forced air system.  Also, make sure that your O/B line is set for an "energize on cool" system, presuming that your heat pump is generating heat (i.e. a call for heat is causing the compressor to run).

Comment: If you'll take the [tour], @Sierratee, you'll see that the proper way to say thanks is to click the up arrow and check mark.